# Store PHP variables in memory between script executions

Tags: php

How can I keep variables in the server's RAM between script executions, and even between different sessions?

Do I need to install some sort of extension, or is this built into PHP somehow?

Comment: Generally this is what you would use a database for.

Comment: What do you want to store and why do you want to store it in memory?

Comment: @Amber , or [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php)

Comment: See also http://php.net/manual/en/function.shm-put-var.php and comments

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Share variables/memory between all PHP processes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605656/share-variables-memory-between-all-php-processes)

Comment: This helped me, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605656/share-variables-memory-between-all-php-processes

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is few options:

Memcache http://memcached.org/ extension. It's RAM based storage engine.

APC [APC - PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) apc code cache allows store variables.

If you don't want any extensions you could store your data into file (serialize, or xml format), and it will be persistent data. Slower then memory storage.

And if you want to store general data, well then there is "one-hundred-two" database engines. 
For example [MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php), [SQLite](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlite.php) or NOSQL [MongoDB](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mongo.php) and more...

Comment: Would a DB not be as slow as a filesystem? I have used files in the past, but was annoyed by the lack of speed

Comment: DB will be faster, because db'a internally optimised for efficiency, uses caching, fast algoritms for data search. And it's more reliable way of storing data.

Comment: You should be using APC if you have a single server, and Memcached - if you work with cluster. That's because Memcached is a bit slower then APC, but **distributed**.

Answer (score 0):

You can cache a variable in the data store using **apc_store()** and apc_add(), then use **apc_fetch()** to get their value. But I think session variables `$_SESSION` would be a good option if your variables are related to only one client. If the variables are **GLOBAL** & are used between many clients, then using **database engines** would also be an option.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. APC is referenced in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10868702/3536236). `$_SESSION` does not apply (or if it does apply you need to elaborate as to how) as the question states "`and even between different sessions`".