# Share variable between processes - PHP

Tags: php

I have a PHP file, say `foo.php` and I am running multiple instances of the same PHP file.

```
php foo.php&
php foo.php&
php foo.php&
php foo.php&
```

I need a variable `bar` inside `foo.php` such that if bar is changed in one running instance, it can be updated in other instances as well.

How can I achieve this?

I tried File Processing - storing value of `bar` in some random file, and reading it from there and updating the same.

From Question - "[Share variables/memory between all PHP processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605656/share-variables-memory-between-all-php-processes)", I got to know about [gearman](http://gearman.org/). But this seems to be using an aeroplane instead of using a bike!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm assuming you want to share the value of variable bar across all instances and sessions (just in-case), in  that case the ideal thing will be to have the variable values stored in a dedicated file on the server and read by the variable when called. a similar trick is used in game development where DLL files are used as shared libraries..

i will further suggest having a script read the value of bar from the server probably  by implementing a timer.