# How does threading and statefulness work in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, process, httpd.conf

I’m trying to understand the process and execution model for Laravel/php running on httpd or in dev mode with php artisan serve. I’ve been struggling to find a resource that answers questions like the following in detail:

- What in-memory state, if any, persists across requests?
- Is the same object ever present on multiple requests?
- How are threads and processes managed?
- What exactly does “view caching” and “route caching” do (some kind of codegen?)

I’m used to frameworks like .NET where one application instance = one process = 1 .NET runtime, where it is possible for an object (eg the value of a static field) to be initialized on app start and used across all requests to the instance. I suspect php works fairly differently, but I’d love to understand the specifics.

An answer to the questions above would be great, as would a link to a resource that covers that material.

Comment: For #1, nothing, unless you manually persist to a DB, FS or similar. For #2, no. For #3, depends on SAPI, such as FPM or CGI. For #4, I don’t know the specifics of Laravel, but I believe it is a serialization of an object’s state.

Comment: Back to #1, nothing is shared in PHP. The request enters, PHP builds global state (global as in variable scope for the request, not across requests), work is done and then everything is torn down. Beyond obvious things like DB and FS, there are ways to do [shared memory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23768204/231316), but usually only for unique situations.